# Is there a way to put a paypal script tag inside a button using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, api, paypal

I am working on implementing smart buttons for a PayPal widget and I was wondering how to go about doing this. My idea right now is to make a button and see if I can fit a script tag inside it that would lead me to make a payment. This is my code so far:

This is from the index.js file

`<button>Donate Here Plz</button>`

this is the reactjs file that was already written before I hopped on the project.

````
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import scriptLoader from "react-async-script-loader";

class PaypalButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      showButton: false,
      price: 1.0,
      priceError: true
    };

    window.React = React;
    window.ReactDOM = ReactDOM;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { isScriptLoaded, isScriptLoadSucceed } = this.props;

    if (isScriptLoaded && isScriptLoadSucceed) {
      this.setState({ showButton: true });
    }
  }

  handleInputChange = e => {
    const re = /^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$/;

    if (e.target.value === "" || re.test(e.target.value)) {
      this.setState({ price: e.target.value });
    }
    if (this.state.price >= 1) {
      this.state.priceError = false;
    } else {
      this.state.priceError = true;
    }
    console.log(this.state.priceError);
  };

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { isScriptLoaded, isScriptLoadSucceed } = nextProps;

    const isLoadedButWasntLoadedBefore =
      !this.state.showButton && !this.props.isScriptLoaded && isScriptLoaded;

    if (isLoadedButWasntLoadedBefore) {
      if (isScriptLoadSucceed) {
        this.setState({ showButton: true });
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const paypal = window.PAYPAL;
    const {
      currency,
      env,
      commit,
      client,
      onSuccess,
      onError,
      onCancel
    } = this.props;

    const { showButton, price } = this.state;

    const payment = () =>
      paypal.rest.payment.create(env, client, {
        transactions: [
          {
            amount: {
              total: price,
              currency
            }
          }
        ]
      });

    const onAuthorize = (data, actions) =>
      actions.payment.execute().then(() => {
        const payment = {
          paid: true,
          cancelled: false,
          payerID: data.payerID,
          paymentID: data.paymentID,
          paymentToken: data.paymentToken,
          returnUrl: data.returnUrl
        };

        onSuccess(payment);
      });

    const style = {
      layout: "vertical", // horizontal | vertical
      size: "medium", // medium | large | responsive
      shape: "rect", // pill | rect
      color: "gold" // gold | blue | silver | white | black
    };

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <form>
          <h3 style={{ justifySelf: "center" }}>Donate Amount</h3>
          <input
            name="donate"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Minimum $1.00"
            value={this.state.price}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            className="donationInput"
          />
        </form>

        <br />
        {showButton && (
          <paypal.Button.react
            style={style}
            env={env}
            client={client}
            commit={commit}
            payment={payment}
            onAuthorize={onAuthorize}
            onCancel={onCancel}
            onError={onError}
          />
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default scriptLoader("https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js")(
  PaypalButton
);```

No error messages show up, but the button does not lead to anything.
````

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like you are trying to use the depreciated version of the checkout api.  There is a new version V2 you can view here [Paypal Checkout Buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/#).

If you want there is an npm package for the new V2 buttons that can be viewed here [NPM react-paypal-button-v2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paypal-button-v2).

That said you can do something like the following which is taken from the npm packages github found here [react-paypal-button-v2 github](https://github.com/Luehang/react-paypal-button-v2) but without the typescript and in functional component form:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const PaypalButton = props => {
  const [sdkReady, setSdkReady] = useState(false);

  const addPaypalSdk = () => {
    const clientID =
      'Your-Paypal-Client-ID';
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = `https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=${clientID}`;
    script.async = true;
    script.onload = () => {
      setSdkReady(true);
    };
    script.onerror = () => {
      throw new Error('Paypal SDK could not be loaded.');
    };

    document.body.appendChild(script);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (window !== undefined && window.paypal === undefined) {
      addPaypalSdk();
    } else if (
      window !== undefined &&
      window.paypal !== undefined &&
      props.onButtonReady
    ) {
      props.onButtonReady();
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);


  //amount goes in the value field we will use props of the button for this   
  const createOrder = (data, actions) => {
    return actions.order.create({
      purchase_units: [
        {
          amount: {
            currency_code: 'USD',
            value: props.amount,
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  };

  const onApprove = (data, actions) => {
    return actions.order
      .capture()
      .then(details => {
        if (props.onSuccess) {
          return props.onSuccess(data);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      });
  };

  if (!sdkReady && window.paypal === undefined) {
    return (
      <div>Loading...</div>
    );
  }

  const Button = window.paypal.Buttons.driver('react', {
    React,
    ReactDOM
  });

  //you can set your style to whatever read the documentation for different styles I have put some examples in the style tag
  return (
    <Button
      {...props}
      createOrder={
        amount && !createOrder
          ? (data, actions) => createOrder(data, actions)
          : (data, actions) => createOrder(data, actions)
      }
      onApprove={
        onSuccess
          ? (data, actions) => onApprove(data, actions)
          : (data, actions) => onApprove(data, actions)
      }
      style={{
        layout: 'vertical',
        color: 'blue',
        shape: 'rect',
        label: 'paypal'
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default PaypalButton;
```

Then you can use this in your component like so:

```
const onSuccess = payment => {
  console.log(payment)
}

const onCancel = data => {
  console.log(data)
};

const onError = err => {
  console.log(err);
};

<PaypalButton
  amount="1.00"
  onError={onError}
  onSuccess={onSuccess}
  onCancel={onCancel}
/>
```

Note this is not tested I just pulled it from the npm packages github and removed the typescript for a little easier reading but it should give you an idea of what to do and how to add your donation logic to the button.  I would highly suggest reading through paypals documentation.  It is painful to go through but necessary.  If you don't feel like messing with creating your own button you can just add the npm package and be on your way pretty easy.

Comment: payment id is getting null.why?

Comment: @Khushi The I'm not entirely sure but if I had to guess it's because the payment hasn't been fully processed at this point.  In this example you can also pass the details from the then block and console log that.  In my experience the order id is what  you need if you are going to check the validity of the transaction against your records on your server that is why I am console logging the data instead of details in the onApprove function.  The documentation is painful to read through but try to read through it to find what information you want to save if you are going to save in your server.

Comment: yea i do that i pass the details from the then block and console it. what i have got is: payment:Object { create_time: "2020-03-09T07:58:00Z", update_time: "2020-03-09T07:59:05Z", id: "1FN65392BW503230D", intent: "CAPTURE", status: "COMPLETED", payer: {…}, purchase_units: (1) […], links: (1) […] } and details: Object { orderID: "1FN65392BW503230D", payerID: "3LNXV55Q55GHE", paymentID: null, billingToken: null, facilitatorAccessToken: "A21AAHXTop8puyaYcAjkKpNe9B09ODed1hRWjs-Mrehs7_WI--aqYzLr6dYmUoQuL05zvvehd4z468BEC7S2ToaG0UVKoXdcA" } in that payment id is null .

Comment: and inorder to validate i pass order id to server then i got  RESORCE_NOT_FOUND and invalid resorce id. and one more thing i do that i checked my bussiness account there is no transaction details happend there. and in my sandbox personal account it reflect the details

Comment: You should only need the orderID to validate on you server.  I get null for the paymentID every time as well you shouldn't need it at this point.  I usually use nodejs and the serverside sdk they provide https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/get-transaction/ .  I find it odd that you are not seeing transaction details in your account though.  Here is a codesandbox that works for me https://codesandbox.io/s/paypal-button-nuqnj . Put your clientID in buttonjs.  Try it and see if you get your sandbox to reflect the transaction.

Comment: in codesandbox i put my client id it working well. But through my project it is not working. same code but not working why? anything i missed?

Comment: Not sure why its not working in your project if the code in the sandbox is working and your using the same code in your project I find it hard to believe it is a code issue but I'm not sure.

Comment: I find out my issue its because i mistakenly add script in index.html i just remove it and now my bussiness accout is reflecting the transaction details.Thank you for your patience and help. And i have on e doubt that is onsucess details contains purchase_units[0].payments.capures[0].seller_protection.dispute_categories . this array contains "ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED" and "UNAUTHORIZED_TRANSACTION" is it any problem?

Comment: These values in the dispute categories are correct and not a problem.  These are the categories that the payer is able to file a dispute under if there is a problem with the product or transaction https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#definition-dispute_category.  They are normal.